# Timespan of Yeshiva "zmanim"

Tags: yeshiva-school

I am going into 1st year post high-school yeshiva and am trying to find the commonality between yeshivos' "zmanim"/semester length and their break times, particularly in 5781, as I have been told that some may differ. What I heard from one person(RC = Rosh Chodesh):

- Elul Zman: 1 month from RC Elul to Yom Kippur;

18 day break until RC Cheshvan

- Winter Zman: 5 months from RC Cheshvan until RC Nissan;

29 day break until RC Iyar

- Summer Zman: 3.3 months from Iyar to Tisha B'av;

20 day break until RC Elul

Is that what it was like for you? Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ועיקר הכולל הכל, יהיה נעקר ונשרש מן העולם השם של 'בין הזמנים', לא יזכר ולא יפקד, רק כל העתים שוים לטובה, יתנהגו במנהג אחד לתורה, כמו שכתוב והגית בו יומם ולילה
- של"ה

Comment: That is awesome.

Comment: Zmanim and sedder weren't created to tell people who wouldn't be learning when they are supposed to go learn. They were created to tell people who wouldn't know when to stop learning that need to takecare of other things. Reb Yisroel Salanter as repeated by Reb Shmuel Berenbaum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most yeshivos have such a learning schedule.

Some "american" yeshivos in Eretz Yisroel follow mostly what you wrote but will shorten the "29 day break until RC Iyar" break either by continuing the zman closer to pesach or starting soon afterwards to enable students to leave and go to american camps which tend to span 8-9 weeks beginning around mid/late-June which is still during the zman for yeshivos.

There is also a special type of yeshiva called "[Zilbermans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivat_Aderet_Eliyahu)" which is located in the Old City of Yerushalayim which, I have been told, has classes every day of the year (including shabbos ) for those who live close enough to attend but do not have classes on tisha baav and yom kippur. Perhaps there are other times they do not have classes as well  but overall they do not have many breaks in their learning schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but to give input as to what Bein HaZmanim is based on:

The Gemara ([Brochos 35B](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.35b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says that Rava told his Talmidim not to come to Yeshiva in Nissin and Tishrei. While the reasons have changed, Yeshivas, with some variations of schedule, have consistently been closed during those months ever since ancient times.The Livish Yeshivas remain open during the Aseres Yemei Teshuva. The Chassidish Yeshivas for the most part do not.

As far as the month of Av is concerned there is more variation. Some  Yeshivas end on Rosh Chodesh, others end on Erev Tisha B'Av. Chassidish Yeshivas for the most part remain open.

An explicit basis in the Rishonim or earlier   for Yeshivas being closed during Av is difficult to find but it seems to have been the case in Lithuanian Yeshiva even prior to the days of the Litvish Chassidish divergence. There is a reference in the 1600s to Yeshiva Students using those weeks to find Shidduchim (because of Tu B'av?) and travel during those weeks

Answer (score 0):

My Yeshiva (R' Lopiansky - Yeshiva of Greater Washington) ended up being significantly different. They have an off shabbos (break from Thursday to Sunday, occasionally Monday or Tuesday) every month, as well as a winter break, pesach break, and full summer. The constant breaks make it easier to keep pushing.